# Copy cell from workbook If condition met

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below snippet of code that I am trying to get to find the cells in range C19:C30 that matches C3 then offset 3 columns but same row and paste it into the cell E4 of the destination workbook. It will run without issue however does not pull anything in and the next line works copying data in.

```
For Each file In folder.Files
Set fromWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(file)
With fromWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
For Each Cell In Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C19:C30")
    If Cell.Value = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C3") Then
    Cell.Offset(0, 3).Offset(r).Value = .Range("E4").Value
    End If
Next
```

Full code if needed

```
Sub ServiceFees()
    Dim r As Long
    Call GetFiles("D:\30\Service Fee Analysis\Data\", r)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub

Sub GetFiles(ByVal path As String, r As Long)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Setting file system object
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim folder As Object
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(path)

Dim subfolder As Object
Dim file As Object

For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
    GetFiles subfolder.path, r
Next subfolder

'Setting the sheet to be copied into
Set destSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ServiceFees")

'Cycling through all files within the directory subfolders
For Each file In folder.Files
    Set fromWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(file)
    With fromWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")
    For Each Cell In Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C19:C30")
        If Cell.Value = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C3") Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 3).Offset(r).Value = .Range("E4").Value
        End If
    Next
        destSheet.Range("A3").Offset(r).Value = .Range("P4").Value
        r = r + 1
    End With
    fromWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Next file

Set fso = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set subfolder = Nothing
Set file = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: `Cell.Offset(0, 3).Offset(r).Value` reference the **active sheet**. Where do you want/need copying?

Answer (score 1):

it seems, you haven't initialized "r" variable with any number. You are only assigning the number when you copying it to another row. Thus, first row, doesn't work.

try initializing it with number 0 or 1, as follows.

```
 Sub ServiceFees()
    Dim r As Long = 0
    .....
 End Sub
```